# Plus Symbols (+) in URLs

Tags: html, url

I am wondering if I will run into any issues with having plus symbols "+" in my URLs. Could these potentially cause problems or even errors?

I wouldn't normally use plus symbols, but my wiki has a feature to more intuitively and simply name pages, but the down side is the url's end up with plus symbols like this: site.com/Really+Cool+Page.

Thanks!

Comment: I know from experience that you can't use URLs like that everywhere, because sometimes the software thinks that you meant real plus signs, and changes them into %2B. Things like that. Better test thoroughly.

Comment: His Wiki software explicitly expects/allows the + separator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The plus symbol is an encoding for a space character

See

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string

You should be fine using it.

Answer (score 2):

Plus ('+') symbol is mostly used for URL Encoding.

Read more about it [here](http://webdesign.about.com/od/forms/a/url_encoding.htm)

Answer (score 2):

The plus symbol is used for URL Encoding.

It is used to encode a space, so '+' equals ' '.

For some more help: http://www.permadi.com/tutorial/urlEncoding/